# The property 'xyz' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart, migration, null-safety

I was upgraded my flutter project version to the latest (2.5.3). then occurred some errors due to unsupported `null-safety`. I had fixed many but still, haven't any idea to fix following `null-safety` to error,

Code

```
itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
 return ListTile(
          subtitle: Text(
            suggestion.stateA == null || suggestion.stateB == null
                ? '${suggestion.city}, ${suggestion.country}'
                : '${suggestion.city}, ${suggestion.state}, ${suggestion.country}',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText,
          ),
        );
 }
```

Errors

```
The property 'stateA' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
The property 'stateB' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
The property 'city' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
The property 'country' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
```

how add the check null-safety above code?

I already try with `!` & `?` Operator but it does not work for me

(i.e. `suggestion!.state`)

Comment: try putting the logic of what to do if it's null outside Text Widget

Comment: I tried that type too. but also still not fixed this issue. :(

Comment: could you try doing something like: `Text(suggestion.city ?? whateverNotNull)`?

Comment: if suggestion!.state not working then please add more info to your question

Comment: There is very little context in your question. Why is your compiler assuming that `suggestion` can be null, is it a nullable variable? If you are sure it is not null, tell your compiler, by making it not nullable.